# Body of request not being passed to API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, rest, mongoose

I'm trying to do a PUT request to an update controller from a react form (Mongoose API). Everything is passing over to the request, except the body. Now, this is my first time using FormData, so I'm almost positive that is where the issue lies, but I can't seem to sort out where the problem is..

**The Submit action from the form**

```
const clickSubmit = () => {
    // console.log('Values on submit before FormData: ', values) // Shows the state object as expected
    let userData = new FormData()
    values.name && userData.append('name', values.name)
    values.email && userData.append('email', values.email)
    values.password && userData.append('password', values.password)
    values.about && userData.append('about', values.about)
    values.photo && userData.append('photo', values.photo)
    update({
      userId: match.params.userId
    }, {
      t: jwt.token
    }, userData).then((data) => {
      if (data && data.error) {
        setValues({...values, error: data.error})
      } else {
        setValues({...values, 'redirectToProfile': true})
      }
    })
  }
```

**The Helper Method that set up the request**

```
const update = async (params, credentials, user) => {
  console.log('The params: ', params)  // passes the user ID just fine
  console.log('The credentials:', credentials) // passes the JWT just fine
  console.log('The user object: ', ...user) // has all the information I'm updating, albeit in an array form that I can't really work with
  try {
    let response = await fetch('/api/users/' + params.userId, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + credentials.t
      },
      body: user
    })
    return await response.json()
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
  }
}
```

**And the controller** I've commented out the rest of the logic to remove the clutter while I TS this issue

```
const update = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req)
  const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId)
  console.log('user after find: ', user) // returns the user that I want to modify from the database
  console.log('body of request: ', req.body) // empty object
}
```

UPDATE:
I was able to get the FormData into an actual object using `Object.fromEntries(user)` - but it still won't pass into the request.. I have tried two ways:

```
const update = async (params, credentials, user) => {
  console.log('The params: ', params)
  console.log('The credentials:', credentials)
  console.log('The user object: ', ...user)
  let infoToUpdate = Object.fromEntries(user)
  console.log('infoToUpdate: ', infoToUpdate);


  try {
    let response = await fetch('/api/users/' + params.userId, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + credentials.t
      },
      body: {
       "name": infoToUpdate.name,
       "email": infoToUpdate.email,
       "about": infoToUpdate.about
      }
    })
    return await response.json()
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
  }
}
```

And

```
const update = async (params, credentials, user) => {
  console.log('The params: ', params)
  console.log('The credentials:', credentials)
  console.log('The user object: ', ...user)
  let infoToUpdate = Object.fromEntries(user)
  console.log('infoToUpdate: ', infoToUpdate);


  try {
    let response = await fetch('/api/users/' + params.userId, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + credentials.t
      },
      body: infoToUpdate
    })
    return await response.json()
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
  }
}
```

But req.body is still an empty object..

Comment: You need something on your server-side to handle `multipart/form-data` request payloads. [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) is a popular choice

Comment: Make sure you're using the appropriate middleware. In your updated example, you're no longer passing formdata at all, and so `app.use(bodyParser.json())` should be sufficient to get your data into the controller.

Comment: Note that if `user.photo` is a `File` (or similar `Blob`), you cannot upload that as JSON. Also, if you _do_ want to send a JSON payload, you should use `body: JSON.stringify(infoToUpdate)`

Answer (score -1):

This has been solved, and it was all my flippin computer's fault..

On a whim, I killed node_modules and the package.lock files and reinstalled the deps.. and it started working.. My guess is that bodyParser didn't fully install..

Thank you all for the help.